# When I use MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URL, Why I get all images that both internal and external?

Tags: android, cursor, usb, media

```
...
Cursor cursor = aContext.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
int index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.DATA);
String path = cursor.getString(index);
...
```

The main code as above, I can get all image both on external and internal, but I only want to obtain thoes image that locate in USB disk, How can I do that? Thanks you very much for your help

Comment: Where do you have an USB disk?